# Using mapbox in scrollview, scrollview sliding to the position where mapbox is put in the page

Tags: android, scrollview, mapbox

Now, when I use mapbox in scrollview, scrollview would slide to the position where mapbox is located in the page, but I want to see the top of the page at the first sight, not the mapbox. BTW, I am using Mapbox 4.0.0 Android SDK.

what I want see is:

[image]

However the weird thing is as follows:

[image]

Comment: What really happens to me is when I first go to the page which mapbox is used, the page would automatically scroll to the position where map is located, because mapbox has auto-focus mechanism. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you are having issues panning/zooming the mapview while it is in a scrollview? This questions been asked here a lot lately...

This snippet of code might resolve the issue for you:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    // Setup the MapView
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ....

    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return mapView.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Lastly, heres my XML

```
ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cameron.mapboxplayground.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Set the starting camera position and map style using xml-->
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        mapbox:access_token="@string/accessToken"
        mapbox:style_url="@string/style_light"
        mapbox:center_latitude="40.7359"
        mapbox:center_longitude="-74.0151"
        mapbox:zoom="10"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I didn't make it clear. What really happens to me is when I first go to the page which mapbox is used, the page would automatically scroll to the position where map is located, because mapbox has auto-focus mechanism. What can I do to prevent this? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There isn't any auto-focus mechanism built into the Mapbox Android SDK. If you edit your question with code examples or pictures I'll be able to better understand the problem and give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        mScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
});
```

Comment: This makes it keeps on the top of the page. If any further, just use getScrollY and smoothScrollTo methods.

Comment: I had the same problem and tried this solution. It works, but there is a very noticeable "flash" when the map has finished loading. The page doesn't seem to scroll fast down and then up again, but it displays something else than the top of the page for a fraction of a second.