# Mapbox - Avoid automatic center

Tags: android, mapbox

I use a Mapbox map in a scrollview. In this scrollview I have the main LinearLayout and inside this, I have 5 areas with different information. The Map is in the third area.

Due to the amount of data in the first and second area, while displaying, the Map area must **not** be visible and to see it, you'll need to scroll.

Unfortunatly, the Mapbox seems to have an "automatic center" sistem: as soon as the Scrollview start to be displayed, it's position is set automaticly to the center of the Map.
So the user has to scroll back to the top of the scrollview.
How to avoid this "initial position feature"?

Note: this is NOT a duplicate question from this: [Using mapbox in scrollview, scrollview sliding to the position where mapbox is put in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692453/using-mapbox-in-scrollview-scrollview-sliding-to-the-position-where-mapbox-is-p)
as the problem is NOT "how to move the map and don't move the scrollview". The problem is the **initial** position of the scrollview. Also the answer "do  mScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);" is NOT acceptable as with that, the scrollview is first centered to the map and AFTER, there is a scroll.

**Edit:** here are two pictures and more details.

[image: Display in vertical mode]

This first snap show the scrollview in vertical mode. I've a first area named "INFORMAÇOES" a second one named "TIPO DE OCORENÇA", a third with the map and after than I have 2 others area.
Due to the size of area 1 and 2, in vertical mode, the map area is partially visible. This snap show the screen at start of display.

[image: Snap in horizontal mode]

This second snap is taken at the same time so at start of display, but in horizontal mode. Of course, the amount of visible data is different. What we can see is that the map area seem to force a scroll in order to be displayed.

After making some test I discovered strange thinks: when you scroll, you commonly set the top of data at top of screen. In the case of the map it's not the case. The first element which appear quickly at start of the display is the Mapbox logo.

Here is the XML part:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout_type"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_map">

            <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                mapbox:zoom="12"
                android:id="@+id/mapview_inter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

The tests I've made:

1 - put a  android:visibility="gone"  in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView. it's not allowed.

2 - put a  android:visibility="invisible"  in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView. it's not allowed.

3 - put a  android:visibility="invisible"  in the linearlayout of the map (linearLayout). Change nothing. The map is not visible but the "scroll" happened.

4 - put a  android:visibility="gone"  in the linearlayout of the map (linearLayout). In that case, that's OK: the "INFORMAÇOES"part of the data is at top. But their is no rendering of the map. So when I perform a

```
  LinearLayout tmp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_map);
  tmp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to see the map, I see... nothing :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add pictures/GIFs of this occurring? I'm not certain I understand the issue.

Comment: i'll do that in a few min. Last test let me think there'is a link with the Mapbox Logo.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should give a either your `LinearLayout` a specific dp size or the `MapView`. Right now you are using `match_parent` for both. You can force the ScrollView to the top by using `scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);` inside the `OnMapReady` callback which fixed the issue for me.